# How to reopen selenium browser in a loop: Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to close the browser and reopen it after a loop

```
class Bot():

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

    def __init__(self):
        self.openyoutube
        self.quitbrowser()

    def openyoutube(self):
        self.driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
        sleep(5)
   
    def quitbrowser(self):
        self.driver.quit()



def main():
    while True: 
        my_bot = Bot()
        sleep(15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But once it tries to start all over, it throws this error:

> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost',
> port=64578): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /session/f7fcdfe14c3e2c75d530b3cbf70348d2/url (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x7fb6d71f8250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61]
> Connection refused'))

Answer (score 1):

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=64578): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/f7fcdfe14c3e2c75d530b3cbf70348d2/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb6d71f8250>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))
```

Generally after this error we reinitialise the driver which you can do by using a try catch for Maxretryerror.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried to catch the MaxRetryError, but still getting the same error. Do I need to import something? Please show an example of how to catch the error. I might be doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Post the way you are doing